# Karma issues with require.js module loading

Tags: node.js, requirejs, pycharm, karma-runner

I'm trying to use the Karma test-runner in PyCharm. I ran the karma init script, and selected to include the Require.js plugin from this init script. Then, when I tried running the test-runner, I got notifications like this: `Uncaught Error: Module name "assert" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

So I had to download assert using "npm install assert", and then include a line like this in my karma.conf.js file: `{pattern: 'node_modules/assert/assert.js', included: true},` in the files array.

But now I am getting a similar complaint like this: `Uncaught Error: Module name "util/" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`, and although I installed using 'npm install util' and the folder now shows up under my node_modules folder, nothing I do seems to fix the problem.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's a requireJS error. You're using it the wrong way... I guess... because you did not share any code!